# How get array by string key?

Tags: php

For example I need get value by string key `$string`:

```
var_dump($arr['privateContacts']); // Works

$string = 'privateContacts';
$arr[$string]; // Does not work returns NULL
```

**Function:**

```
function existSecureField($arr, $string, $key){ var_dump($arr[$string]); die();...
```

**Call function:**

```
existSecureField($secureFields, 'privateContacts', 1)
```

**Var_dump in function existSecureField():**

```
var_dump($arr);

array(2) { ["privatePersonal"]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(1) [3]=> int(1) } ["privateContacts"]=> array(2) { [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(1) } }
```

Comment: Works fine for me? And how can this return `NULL`?!

Comment: Did you forget the `var_dump` part?

Comment: `$arr[$string]` is correct. You're doing something else wrong that you're not showing.

Comment: @Danil If you have a error then it's not in these lines

Comment: @Danil for what is the `$key` and where is the code from the first box? Like in the function or where? And what do you expect from `$arr[$string];` to be the output?

Comment: Hmm for me it works, or i do some wrong :( http://codepad.org/STaT1OUY

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it must work. I tried this one out:

```
         $array = array("key" => "value");
           $k = "key";
               echo $array[$k];
```

Works just fine. **$arr[$string];** is not a statement and it must give an error.